# Can solr 3.6 work fine with tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, solr

After tomcat 6 starting (page `http://localhost:8080` show tomcat start page) I call java -jar start.jar in .../example directory. This command execute well without any exceptions but when I tried open page `http://localhost:8080/solr/` I got 404 exception. What should I do to fix this problem?

P.s. I used [this tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_2/doc-files/tutorial.html) to setup solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that tutorial it looks like `java -jar start.jar` is using an embedded Jetty server. What is the output when you run that command? It should tell you what port the app is listening on.

If the output were `2012-03-27 17:11:32.343:INFO::Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983` then you'd want to point your browser to `localhost:8983`.

Comment: Thank, it's working. Only now I looking at log and find this string. Great thanks for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run solr with tomcat and `java -jar star.jar`. That doesn't sound right. You should do one of those. Install the `war` file in tomcat will install it in using tomcat.